# How to write formula for cell in Excel?

Tags: excel

I'm working on excel where I've few columns. I would like to make SQL insert operation from the records in sheet.

There are chances of cell to be empty and this is where I am unable to continue. I need to check:

```
if(cell is empty) 
   insert null 
else
   insert value
```

How can I implement it inside formula?

`=CONCONTENATE("INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES"("A1,if(A2="",NULL,"'","A2","'"))`

correct me if anything wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example of a working function would be:

```
=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO TABLE MyTable (Col1, Col2) VALUES ('", A2, "', ", IF(ISBLANK(B2), "NULL", CONCATENATE("'", B2, "'")), ")")
```

This assumes that you are inserting two values from the same Excel row, adds quotes around values to allow you to insert text strings, and then replaces any blank values with `NULL`. The `IF()` statement contains its own `CONCATENATE()` to add quotes around the value if it exists (you wouldn't want quotes around the  `NULL` value).

The screenshot below shows the setup and results:

[image]